# Charles proxy push back buffer is full

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, charles-proxy

My use case I am trying to decipher an api call through charles proxy but on an IPhone. Now some of these IPhone's I am getting a wierd error message

> IO:Push Back Buffer is full

It happens only on one of the Phones and rest of the phones work perfectly fine. And they are specific to only some of the API calls. I had the same issue on Android and I had to reset the Android to get it to work. Not sure if anyone had an issue like this with Charles.
Phone: Iphone 6S
OS: 10

Screenshot of the error[image]

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same in google SDK help forum, you guys can go through the response [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/w3R7W2d2Hyc)

detailed answer here:

ok now looks like one of my colleague found a solution for this problem . So lot of us were effected with this issue every now and then and problem with come and go away on its own and more over this seemed to effect only the Ad related Api calls.

Solution: We just deleted the all the cache and data from the Play Store App in the Device Settings -- Applications Manager --> Delete all the cache data in the pay services.

This basically took care of the problem immediately although it did crash the App for  2-3 times but worked like a charm after that. So now this does point to a Bug in the Ad mobs SDK where it builds this cache overtime and starts complaining about it when it cannot handle it.